# Handling hotkeys with modifiers

Tags: c++, winapi, hotkeys

I'm using `RegisterHotKey` to modify certain key combinations. For example, I want to replace Alt+Q with 'A' - I do this by simply registering Alt+Q hotkey and handling it by sending 'A'-up/'A'-down with SendInput. But Alt is still held down, so the target window receives Alt+A. How do programs such as AutoHotkey handle it, do they send an Alt-up every time an Alt+key is handled?

Comment: <kbd>Alt+</kbd> key combinations are handled differently in the Win32 API by a window's message pump. When <kbd>Alt</kbd> is depressed, keys send a `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` and `WM_SYSKEYUP` event instead of the traditional `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`. It is possible that this is related.

Comment: I doubt using `RegisterHotKey()` to generate additional keyboard input is a very common use case.

Comment: If you know that the Alt key is down then just send a up event for the key.

Comment: Okay I checked what keys AHK actually sent, and it does indeed send alt-up, then the required keys, then alt-down. Except for alt, it also sends control-up/control-down to prevent alt from activating menus.